# Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) 64-bit doesn`t detect wireless

Tags: debian, wifi

I can`t use my wi-fi on my dual boot laptop. In Windows it works perfectly, but in Debian it not.

**> ip a**:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 18:31:bf:74:90:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.31.220/24 brd 192.168.31.255 scope global dynamic enp4s0
   valid_lft 42027sec preferred_lft 42027sec
inet6 fe80::1a31:bfff:fe74:9024/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**> lsusb**:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card 
Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b57a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**> lspci**:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5910 (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
00:1e.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO UART #0 (rev 31)
00:1e.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO SPI #0 (rev 31)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a171 (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c8d (rev ff)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 24fd (rev 78)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

**> lspci -knn | grep Net -A2**:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0010]
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Do you use NetworkManager or something else?

Comment: No, just clear installation

Comment: ahh, ok. please wait. you need to install firmware drivers

Comment: Where could I find them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As sudo, do the following:

```
cat "deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi
modprobe -r iwlwifi
modprobe iwlwifi
```

It should work now.